# How to increase limit of messages for WebSocketSession

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I wrote simple chat service on Spring WebFlux (Reactor). WebSocketHandler part looks like

```java
public class ChatWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {
    private final Flux<String> outputEvents;
    private final Sinks.Many<Message> eventPublisher = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

    public ChatWebSocketHandler(){
        this.outputEvents = Flux.from(messages)
                .replay(10)
                .autoConnect();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(final WebSocketSession session) {
        return session.receive()
                .log()
                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                .filter(msg -> messageValidationService.isMessageValid(msg.getText()))
                .doOnNext(msg -> eventPublisher.tryEmitNext(msg))
                .zipWith(session.send(outputEvents.map(session::textMessage)))
                .then();
    }
}
```

This is works fine only for first 32 messages, messages are incomes and goes back as expected, but after 32 messages, server are stop reacting. No any logs (even on debug level) after 32th message. If client do reconnect it can sent another 32 messages.

Log of .log() looks like

```
2023-10-04T14:33:37.317+03:00  INFO 15812 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.Peek.1                      : onSubscribe(FluxPeek.PeekSubscriber)
2023-10-04T14:33:37.320+03:00  INFO 15812 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.Peek.1                      : request(32)
2023-10-04T14:33:37.383+03:00  INFO 15812 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.Peek.1                      : onNext("text")
2023-10-04T14:33:37.383+03:00  INFO 15812 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.Peek.1                      : onNext("text")
2023-10-04T14:33:37.383+03:00  INFO 15812 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.Flux.Peek.1                      : onNext("text")
... another 29 same lines
```

Where is set that limit? Could I increase it?

Comment: There is no such inherent limit. More likely, there's a problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I agree, it could be problem with a code, but I can't understand where exactly it is wrong. If you could point me to the problem I'll be appreciate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess I found the solution.
I changed prefetch from request(32) to request(unbound) as:

```java
 return session.receive()
                .log()
                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                .filter(msg -> messageValidationService.isMessageValid(msg.getText()))
                .doOnNext(msg -> eventPublisher.tryEmitNext(msg))
                .limitRate(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .zipWith(session.send(outputEvents.map(session::textMessage)))
                .then();
```

It's helped.